# Load properties for an appointment using EWS

Tags: c#, exchangewebservices, appointment

I am using Exchange Web Services (EWS) for loading calendar appointments.

```
myService.FindAppointments(FolderId, calendarView);
```

The returned appointments don't have the needed 'Body' Attribute. Therefore I   execute `LoadPropertiesForItems()`

```
myService.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item it in myAppointments select it, PropertySet.FirstClassProperties);
```

This works as expected, but the Appointment body is returned in HTML format.

I tried to change that by manipulating the `RequestedBodyType`.

```
myService.LoadPropertiesForItems(from Item it in myAppointments select it, new PropertySet(PropertySet.FirstClassProperties){RequestedBodyType = BodyType.Text});
```

This produces the following error:

> You must load or assign this property before you can read ist value.

How do I change the body return value from HTML format to plain text?

Comment: You should show the full code sample your using (eg you don't show the line that produces the error and also I would suggest you break your code out into multiple lines it really makes what your doing hard to follow for anybody trying to maintain it. You can also enable tracing on the service object https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/exchange-server-2010/dd633676(v%3Dexchg.80) that would allow you see the actual request that gets made to the server so you can see if it is requesting the body.

Comment: Agree with Glen.  Full code block and server request/response headers and body will be useful.